# Back button not showing up in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I was coding my app and got way ahead in my intent. I noticed that the back button that's suppose to be on the top left corner has disappeared. I've been trying to get it show up again but everything I've tried doesn't work. I've tried to put codes in but still the back button doesn't come out. Can anybody help me? I'm fairly new to IOS Development.

[As you can see the back button is nowhere to be found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWsPD.png)

This is my code for that specific wrong area.

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isEditing, onDismiss: {}) {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.blue, Color.yellow, Color.yellow]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    TextField("", text: $newLandingName)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .alignmentGuide(HorizontalAlignment.center) { _ in
                            return UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2
                        }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button("Add Photos") {
                            isPresentingImagePicker = true
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            isPresentingWriteView = true
                        }) {
                            Text("Write about it")
                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            isPresentingWriteView = true
                        }
                        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentingWriteView) {
                            NavigationView {
                                WriteView(text: $newLandingName, isPresented: $isPresentingWriteView)
                                    .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
                                    .navigationBarItems(
                                        leading:
                                            Button(action: {
                                        isEditing = false
                                        isPresentingWriteView = false
                                    }) {
                                        Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                                        .imageScale(.large)
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `.fullScreenCover` which doesn't have a back button. What you could use is the `dismiss` environment.

Read more about it here:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-a-view-dismiss-itself